# Can we deploy wsp in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, solution-package, sandbox-solution

I wish to deploy a `WSP` in sharepoint online site collection.
Unfortunately, when I upload the `WSP`, I am getting below error:

```
Activation of solutions with sandboxed code has been disabled in this site collection. 
Contact your administrator to enable activation using the guidance published here.
```

Comment: Please check the answers given [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c339513f-1f55-4af7-9e96-18fd2bfbfda4/cannot-activate-sandboxed-solutions-in-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint). this might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The wsp must be a type of sandbox not farm solution.. this link describes how we can deploy sandbox wsp solution to SharePoint online : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/deploying-the-solution-in-sharepoint-online/